# Deep Linking into Netflix on Samsung Tizen Smart TV

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I am writing an app for a Samsung Smart TV running Tizen. My app shows a list of curated Netflix titles. When the user clicks, my app should launch the Netflix app and have it start playing that title. According to the documentation, the code should look something like this.

The format of the PAYLOAD isn't specified, and the settings for some other values (such as "uri") aren't clear.

Can anybody help me with sample code that deep links?

```
let uri = null;
let payload = {values: JSON.stringify({videoIdx: 'https://www.netflix.com/watch/80219127'})};
let data = new tizen.ApplicationControlData('PAYLOAD', [JSON.stringify(payload)]);
let appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl('http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/view',
                                              uri, null, null, [data], null);
tizen.application.launchAppControl(
    appControl,
    href,
    param => console.log('launch success', param),
    error => console.log('launch error', error.message)
);
```